# Como funciona a importação de bibliotecas no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, biblioteca

Nas linguagens de programação como Java, C# e C, quando queremos utilizar algum comando ou função devemos incluir a biblioteca onde contém os comandos que queremos ou as classes se for linguagem orientada a objeto, veja os exemplos:

Classe `Scanner` do Java que pertence ao pacote `util`, usamos o comando `import` para utilizar esta classe:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Codigo...
```

Classe `Regex` do C# que pertence ao pacote `RegularExpressions`, usamos o comando `using` para utilizar esta classe:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Codigo...
```

Função `pow()` do C que pertence a biblioteca `math.h`, neste caso utilizamos o `#include` para utilizar a função:

```
#include <math.h>

Codigo...
```

---

Porem, em JavaScript eu percebo que não é assim, eu apenas digito o comando que eu quero por exemplo `console.log()` ou `array.push('Stack')` e utilizo o método ou classe que eu quiser.

#### Minha dúvida:

Eu gostaria de saber como funciona a importação de bibliotecas no JavaScript e como o JavaScript gerencia suas bibliotecas tantas como da própria linguagem como as de terceiros?

Comment: Se tiver alguma sugestão de melhoria pode deixar um comentário por favor.

Comment: `+1` esta pergunta é muito importante para o JavaScript. Porque o modelo "nativo" tem dado muitas dores de cabeça, porque houve uma guerra grande entre AMD e CJS no passado e porque o futuro está aí com ES6 harmony. Dei uma resposta +/- sucinta. Espero que ajude a perceber os conceitos pelo menos.

Comment: @Sergio sim, e esta minha duvida tem sido uma barreira para mim, já que eu vim do programação para desktop :) vou ler sua resposta com calma :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sendo conciso pode dizer-se que há 3 gerações diferentes no que respeita a importar bibliotecas.

- incluíndo a biblioteca no espaço global (a mais antiga e mais comum)
- usando gestores de pacotes/bibliotecas/dependências (para quem sabe e precisa)
- usando `import` (o futuro, ES6 e ES7)

A maneira mais comum ainda hoje é importar para o espaço global, inserindo o ficheiro diretamente na página. Exemplos disso são o `jQuery`, `Angular`, `Mootools`, etc quando carregado no HTML com por exemplo:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Dessa maneira as variáveis que forem globais nesse ficheiro serão globais na minha aplicação.

Isso é simples, mas pode causar problemas quando estamos a importar código que exporta muitas variáveis/nomes para o espaço global. Se pensar-mos que cada aplicação pode ter 20 ficheiros `.js` a serem carregados então é fácil perceber que a probablidade de sobreposição de nomes e variáveis que apagam outras é grande. Isto funciona bem em projetos pequenos e onde o autor tem controlo/conhecimento de que ficheiros inclui na aplicação.

Mais tarde surgiram gerenciadores como o [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/) e o [browserify](http://browserify.org/) (que converte módulos no Node.js para o browser).

A ideia é simples, estes programs carregam as bibliotecas necessárias e as suas dependências e depois expõe variáveis escolhidas dessas bibliotecas a um escopo defenido/limitado. Ou seja, o código que temos nunca é corrido no espaço global, mas sim dentro de funções para limitar o escopo e só com acesso às variáveis que o gerneciador de módulos tiver configuradas. Basicamente, exemplo minimalista:

```
requirejs(['jquery'], function( $ ) {
    // aqui dentro o $ do jQuery está disponivel.
    // o código da aplicação coloca-se a partir daqui
});
```

Paralelo a esta realidade mais ou menos habitual no browser surgiu o Node.js, que é JavaScript no lado do servidor. Aí foi adotado o modelo CJS. Que basicamente faz com que cada ficheiro **nunca** exporta para o espaço global, e tudo o que entra no ficheiro (módulo) tem de entrar via `require`.

```
var $ = require('jquery');
exports.myExample = function () {};
```

Isto seria o exepmlo equivalente, se bem que o jQuery não se usa no Node.js. Mas segúindo a comparação vê-mos que dentro desse ficheiro o `$` está disponivel depois de requerido o módulo e atribuído à variável. O `exports` é a prta de passagem para o mundo exterior e é o que vai ser passado à proxima variável que fizer `var x = require(etc...);`

**O futuro** é usar `[import`][3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) que faz parte das especificações ES6 e ES7 mas que ainda não está disponivel nos browsers. Estes módulos (em tempos chamados de Harmony) são inspirados no modelo do Node.js (CJS). Apesar de isto pertencer ao futuro, é contudo possivel hoje escrever JavaScript com esta sintaxe e depois converter para o browser com Babelify (Babel + Browserify), que são simuladores (bem fiáveis e muito usados). Assim escre-ve-se código que não precisa ser mudado no futuro.

Esta nova maneira de carregar dependências é muito útil e esperada. Neste caso futuro a sintaxe é:

```
// para importar todas as variáveis globais nesse "meu-modulo"
// e colocar numa nova variável chamada "meuModulo":
import * as meuModulo from "meu-modulo"; 

// para importar somente a variável meuModulo desse "meu-modulo"
import {meuModulo} from "meu-modulo"; 

// para importar e dar novo nome ao mesmo tempo (multiplos nomes/variáveis neste exemplo)
import {meuModulo as m, calculadora as c} from "meu-modulo";
```

Uma diferença importante entre este modelo e CJS é que na ES6/7 é possivel usar o export multiplas vezes para disponibilizar essas funcionalidades a "quem importar" esse ficheiro.

Um exemplo:

ficheiro `main.js`

```
import {closest, getElements} from 'utils';
// ou até import * as utils from 'utils'
getElements('div').forEach(el => {
    el.innerHTML = 'foo';
});
```

ficheiro `utils.js`

```
export function getElements(what, rel) {
    if (typeof what != 'string' && typeof what != 'undefined') return what.tagName ? [what] : what;
    var els = (rel || document).querySelectorAll(what);
    return [].slice.call(els);
}
export function getClosest(el, selector) {
    while (el && !el.matches(selector)) {
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return el;
}
```