# Importar módulos criados pelo usuário no javascript

Tags: javascript, import, módulo-ecmascript

Eu li nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127438/como-funciona-a-importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-bibliotecas-no-javascript/127445#127445) aqui no site que posso importar módulos em javascript de forma similar ao que é feito no python. No entanto, não estou conseguindo aplicar isso no JS.

Segue um exemplo. No python varia:

```
#arquivo mym.py
def my_sqr(a):
    return a**(1/2)
```

Em outro arquivo:

```
#arquivo main.py
from mym import my_sqr

my_sqr(9)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Já no javascripit:

```
//arquivo mym.js
export my_sqr = function(a){
    return a**(1/2)
}
```

Em main.js

```
import {my_sqr} from 'mym'

mym(9)
```

Erro:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema está na configuração do projeto. O node por padrão não entende es6 e es5, isso varia de acordo com a engine do V8 utilizada no node, a sintaxe padrão seria utilizar

`module.exports`

Se você quiser utilizar es6 deve usar um compilador, recomendo o babel.

`npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/node`

**Daí você pode utilizar**

`export default my_sqr`

`import my_sqr from 'mym'`